Set Azure Container Instance variable using release pipeline YAML and AzDevOps variable group
I want to set Azure Container Instance (ACI) custom environment variables for a .net 8 application using release pipeline YAML and AzDevOps group variable.
I want to link the respective AzDevops variable group for DEV, QA, PROD to the respective AzDevops Release pipeline stages as the same variables may have different values for DEV/QA/PROD. The idea is for Container app runtime override the values of appsettings.json from environmentVariables if defined.
Microsoft link example here only uses hardcoded values, that works but I need to use variables.
For example appsettings.json:
"ConnectionString":
{
 "DefaultConnection":""
}

YAML would be
environmentVariables:
    -name: "ConnectionString__DefaultConnection"
     value: $(ConnectionString.DefaultConnection) #$(ConnectionString_DefaultConnection)

When I link the AzDevops variable group to release pipeline stage using the dot notation like ConnectionString.DefaultConnection the release pipeline log shows the proper values and prints it as [ConnectionString_DefaultConnection] but for some reason the value is not recognized when I put it in YAML. Am I doing the value variable syntax wrong?
Do I need to add variable group like so in the deployment.yaml?
variables:
- group: ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'dev') }}:
    - dev-variables
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'qa') }}:
    - qa-variables

The deployment.yaml file, pls note the dot in variable name
apiVersion: '2021-10-01'
location: northcentralus
name: aci-cc-dev
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
properties:
  imageRegistryCredentials: # Credentials to pull a private image
  - server: myacrname.azurecr.io
    username: myusername
    password: ###ACR_PASSWORD###
  osType: Linux
  subnetIds:
   - id: "/subscriptions/1111111111111111111/resourceGroups/rg-prod-network-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet/subnets/apps"
     name: apps
  ipAddress:
    type: Private
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '8080'
  restartPolicy: Always
  containers:
    - name: myaci-api
      properties:
        image: myacrname.azurecr.io/mycontainerapp-api:###BUILD_ID###
        environmentVariables:
          - name: PORT
            value: '8080'
          #- name: ConnectionStrings__DefaultDbConnection
          #  value: $(CONNECTIONSTRINGS_DEFAULTDBCONNECTION)
          - name: ConnectionStrings__DefaultDbConnection
            value: $(ConnectionStrings.DefaultDbConnection)
        ports:
          - port: 8080
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1.0
            memoryInGB: 2.0
    


Am I doing the value variable syntax wrong - maybe not. Are you referencing the variable group at the job, stage or pipeline level? Can you double-check that the variable is available in the job where it is being used?

Thanks @RuiJarimba, I have attached screenshots in original question showing the variable group mapping (C is 1st letter of variablegroup name in DEV scope) and the deployment.yaml file which is used as part of the below command, the yaml doesn't refer the group name. az container create --resource-group myResourceGroup --file deployment.yaml

Please edit your question and paste the code as text, not images.

One way to dynamically set environment variables when using az container create command in an Azure DevOps pipeline is to use the following options:

--environment-variables: A list of environment variables for the container. Space-separated values in key=value format.
--secure-environment-variables: A list of secure environment variables for the container. Space-separated values in key=value format.

Example - running the CLI in a Bash shell or Azure Cloud Shell:
az create ... \
--environment-variables 'PORT'='8080' \
--secure-environment-variables 'ConnectionStrings__DefaultDbConnection'='$(ConnectionStrings.DefaultDbConnection)'

If you use the Windows Command Prompt, specify the variables with double-quotes, such as --environment-variables "PORT"="8080"
The above example probably doesn't work with the --file option, though. You might need to set the whole container configuration such as ports, requests etc using the corresponding options:
az container create --resource-group
                    [--acr-identity]
                    [--add-capabilities]
                    [--allow-escalation]
                    [--assign-identity]
                    [--azure-file-volume-account-key]
                    [--azure-file-volume-account-name]
                    [--azure-file-volume-mount-path]
                    [--azure-file-volume-share-name]
                    [--cce-policy]
                    [--command-line]
                    [--cpu]
                    [--dns-name-label]
                    [--drop-capabilities]
                    [--environment-variables]
                    [--file]
                    [--gitrepo-dir]
                    [--gitrepo-mount-path]
                    [--gitrepo-revision]
                    [--gitrepo-url]
                    [--image]
                    [--ip-address {Private, Public}]
                    [--location]
                    [--log-analytics-workspace]
                    [--log-analytics-workspace-key]
                    [--memory]
                    [--name]
                    [--no-wait]
                    [--os-type {Linux, Windows}]
                    [--ports]
                    [--priority]
                    [--privileged]
                    [--protocol {TCP, UDP}]
                    [--registry-login-server]
                    [--registry-password]
                    [--registry-username]
                    [--restart-policy {Always, Never, OnFailure}]
                    [--role]
                    [--run-as-group]
                    [--run-as-user]
                    [--scope]
                    [--seccomp-profile]
                    [--secrets]
                    [--secrets-mount-path]
                    [--secure-environment-variables]
                    [--sku]
                    [--subnet]
                    [--subnet-address-prefix]
                    [--vnet]
                    [--vnet-address-prefix]
                    [--vnet-name]
                    [--zone]

Please refer to the command's documentation for more details.

Thanks @RuiJarimba, it didn't work for me. When I included the $variable in the az container create command like you suggested it did pick up the values of variable for the command and prints the values even with --secure-environment-variable option but it still does not create the environment variables in the ACI, the json is blank in log and also in the portal Properties for ACI.

The syntax below is used to DevOps pipeline yaml not Azure container deployment.yaml.
variables:
- group: ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'dev') }}:
    - dev-variables
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'qa') }}:
    - qa-variables

To set ConnectionStrings__DefaultDbConnection in deployment.yaml for different pipeline stage, you can use a placeholder in deployment.yaml, and use DevOps task replacetokens@6 to replace it with target value.
The deployment.yaml sample:

The variable group:

The DevOps yaml sample:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: dev
    variables:
    - group: dev-variables
    jobs:
     - job: job1
       steps:
         - task: replacetokens@6
           inputs:
             sources: '**/deployment.yaml'
        
         - script: cat deployment.yaml  
         # add you deployment task...
  
  - stage: prod
    variables:
    - group: prod-variables
    jobs:
     - job: job2
       steps:
         - task: replacetokens@6
           inputs:
             sources: '**/deployment.yaml'
        
         - script: cat deployment.yaml
         # add you deployment task...

For each stage, it will have different value for connectionstring for deployment.


Thanks @WadeZhou please see my response to RuiJarimba above few minutes back, how the variable values were picked up without doing token replacement in the az container cli command. My thought is it should work the same way for YAML automatically when I am referring the variable in yaml, since the Release pipeline is mapped to the variable group, it should replace without me having to do it explicitly. But I believe what you are suggesting will work, looks like that's my only option left.

--environment-variables flag is supported for az container create command, however, when you’re using a YAML file with the --file flag, you should define your environment variables directly in the YAML file under the environmentVariables section. Hence, If you would like to dynamically use the value, you could try token replacement task as above.

Hello WadeZhou, replacetoken throwing below error on the Linux agent.
Starting: replacetokens
Task         : Replace Tokens
Description  : Replace tokens in text based files
Version      : 6.0.6
Author       : Guillaume ROUCHON
Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://github.com/qetza/replacetokens-task/blob/master/tasks/ReplaceTokensV6/README.md) (v6.0.6)
##[error]The current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only. For example, written for Windows Desktop PowerShell.
Finishing: replacetokens


@ManasPadhi,  i confirm the task replacetokens@6(version 6.0.6)  works fine with ubuntu-latest agent.  What's your agent machine? Please give a try with Ubuntu-latest agent.

Thanks Wade for confirming that it works with ubuntu-latest, just learnt that ours is centos 7.9.2009.

You are welcome :). Please use ubuntu-latest agent or set up a new self-host agent based on ubuntu OS, the task could not work on centos. Let me know if you have any queries.

Thanks Wade, I finally got it working, the app is hosted on ACI and running, however there is one issue. Since this approach replaces the tokens in deployment.yaml file in the build Pipeline, when I change the variable value in the Az DevOps Library I have to do a fresh build and a release. I remember in my last company when we changed variable values in library we just had to create a new release, no new build was necessary, I was new to Az DevOps then, so didn't realize all the magic happening behind the scene.

@ManasP, glad to know it's working now! Since it replaces the token in deployment.yaml file in your build pipeline, you need to transfer the new yaml to release pipeline, eg: from artifact . Hence you need to run the build firstly. Happy day! :)
